# Big size prints

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution, ppi

Some People asked me to make some designs for their store frontpage.

I know the illustration programs is the best to keep the resolution hight.

But the frontpage contains pictures like food & drinks and because of this I am afraid to lose the quality because the size is 4M * 4M.

I've edited the pictures in Photoshop using real sizes and 300 ppi, but the file size is bigger than 2GB.

What do I have to do to make the file size smaller yet keep the quality.

Another question; the frontpage contains windows. I have to cut one picture according to these windows. Is there any other software instead of Photoshop or Illustrator to cut and distribute the pictures according to the frontpage windows?

Comment: @Bart don't you understand? IT'S BIG SIZED PRINTS!

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, you really need to speak with the company that will be printing the actual job. They will have prepress guidelines that address your questions exactly.

However, they will likely suggest image resolution of about 100 to 150ppi (Pixels Per Inch) at final size. 300ppi is probably higher than required, and as you've discovered, makes absolutely massive files.

The other thing to consider is the original resolution of the images. If they were low (say 50ppi at final size) and you upsampled them in Photoshop to 300ppi, you just made gigantic files that are going to gain you very little, if anything, in final print quality.

As for cutting the picture for the windows, I'm going to assume you are talking about tiling or panelling them. You can do this very easily in Illustrator with multiple artboards. You can setup bleed on the artboards to act as panel overlaps.